# Regular Expression - WordPress Plugin

Tags: regex, wordpress

I was learning about how to write a plugin in WordPress and what my plugin is supposed to do is to replace all

```
`code`
```

and make them

```
<span class="code">code</span>
```

### My Code

```
function format_code($content) {
    $match = preg_match_all('/`.+\`/', $content, $matches);

    if($match)
    {  
        $theContent = preg_replace('/`.+\`/', '<span class="code">$0</span>', $content);
        $theContent = preg_replace('/`/', '', $theContent);
    }  

    else  
    {  
        $theContent = $content;  
    }   

    return $theContent; 
}

add_filter('the_content', 'format_code');
```

I have been able to do this `code` but to remove the (`) I used this [I basically removed all the `]

```
$theContent = preg_replace('/`/', '', $theContent);
```

Is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use capturing brackets and '$1' in your replacement:

```
$theContent = preg_replace('/`(.+)\`/', '<span class="code">$1</span>', $content);
```

(Is that what you meant?)

As an aside, why do you escape your second backtick but not the first in that regex?

Also, you may want to consider having your regex:

```
/`([^`]+)`/
```

To avoid, for example, `"This is ' code ' and this is more ' code '"` being replaced by `"This is <span class="code">code ' and this is more ' code</span>"`, because the `.+` was greedy and matched too much. (Replace the single quotes with the backticks in the example I gave, I can't get the literal backticks to appear with this wiki markup!)

Comment: I wonder why I didn't check your answer properly before. The old method was a bit buggy as you pointed out. Thanks a lot for pointing out the more appropriate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a **capturing group** like this:

```
$theContent = preg_replace('/`(.+)\`/', '<span class="code">$1</span>', $content);
```

...then that saves you the second step.

Surrounding an item in parentheses in regular expressions causes it to be "captured" - note in the above I also changed `$0` to `$1` so I'm only "using" the item in parentheses, but it's replacing the entire "found" chunk.